# Android application has stopped unexpectedly

Tags: android, eclipse

I try to launch my Android application on my phone (Sony Ericsson Xperia Neo). It launches normally, but when I try to open it, I see a message saying so **sorry, you application has stopped unexpectedly, please try again** and the button **force close**. Also the size of the installed application is only 820KB, though it has to be something like 8-10MB.
btw, my application runs fine on tablets, problems only on phone. 
Any help ? thanks.

Here it's logcat output

```
01-12 18:09:59.345: D/dalvikvm(2402): DexOpt: couldn't find field Landroid/content/res/Configuration;.smallestScreenWidthDp
01-12 18:09:59.345: W/dalvikvm(2402): VFY: unable to resolve instance field 17
01-12 18:09:59.345: D/dalvikvm(2402): VFY: replacing opcode 0x52 at 0x0012
01-12 18:09:59.345: D/dalvikvm(2402): VFY: dead code 0x0014-011f in Lcom/example/mis/MainActivity;.onCreate (Landroid/os/Bundle;)V
01-12 18:09:59.375: D/AndroidRuntime(2402): Shutting down VM
01-12 18:09:59.375: W/dalvikvm(2402): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x2aac8578)
01-12 18:09:59.435: E/AndroidRuntime(2402): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-12 18:09:59.435: E/AndroidRuntime(2402): java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: android.content.res.Configuration.smallestScreenWidthDp
01-12 18:09:59.435: E/AndroidRuntime(2402):     at com.example.mis.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:59)
01-12 18:09:59.435: E/AndroidRuntime(2402):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
01-12 18:09:59.435: E/AndroidRuntime(2402):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1623)
01-12 18:09:59.435: E/AndroidRuntime(2402):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1675)
01-12 18:09:59.435: E/AndroidRuntime(2402):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:121)
01-12 18:09:59.435: E/AndroidRuntime(2402):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:943)
01-12 18:09:59.435: E/AndroidRuntime(2402):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-12 18:09:59.435: E/AndroidRuntime(2402):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
01-12 18:09:59.435: E/AndroidRuntime(2402):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3701)
01-12 18:09:59.435: E/AndroidRuntime(2402):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-12 18:09:59.435: E/AndroidRuntime(2402):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
01-12 18:09:59.435: E/AndroidRuntime(2402):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
01-12 18:09:59.435: E/AndroidRuntime(2402):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:624)
01-12 18:09:59.435: E/AndroidRuntime(2402):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: do you have any logs?

Comment: can you post the whole logcat?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide logcat and some relevant code for us to see what is wrong. Also how can you know that app should be 8-10 mb? There is no compulsion that any app should atleast be of any particular size. It all depends on the amount of data that your app has. 820kb is normal

Comment: @user3187408 No it isn't please google about what are logcat errors and how to copy them.

Comment: Can you provide more info? how do you install the application on the phone? what code is running? OS version of tablets that it runs fine? OS version of the phone?

Comment: @user3187408 edit your initial post and add full logcat there!

Comment: Please do not post logcats or code in comments.  Edit your question.

Comment: in my manifest file I wrote - android:minSdkVersion="8",   android:targetSdkVersion="17"
on tablet it was android 4.1, on phone - android 2.3.4, so as I understand no problem with it.
also - I changed the application language, it was in english, now I made the farsi version, and on my phone  it was 10mb, now - not  possible to be 820kb

Comment: From your log this field is accessed here `MainActivity.java:59`

Answer (score 1):

The error refers to `smallestScreenWidthDp` which is something introduced in Android 3.2. You say that your phone is running Android 2.3.4 so you are calling some kind of code or configured something in your Manifest file that is causing the error.